# How to auto load the datatable after inserting the data using Ajax

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hi developers **I have here my modules that i need to get the customers data in the first row after user registered.**

**I have question is there way to load every seconds the datatable? do I need to set interval for this to load every second?**

I have here my function listing all the customers data

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'/logic_get_customer_data',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {

      var details = response.data;

      $.each(details, function (index, el) {

          var stringify = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));

          var customer_name_each = stringify['customer_name'];
          var customer_address_each = stringify['customer_address'];
          var customer_email_each = stringify['customer_email'];
          var customer_number_each = stringify['customer_number'];
          var store_location_each = stringify['customer_location'];
          var customer_order_note_each = stringify['customer_order_note'];
          var customer_registered_each = stringify['customer_registered'];
          var customer_id_each = stringify['customer_id'];
          var action_each = '<button id="show_cart_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value='+customer_id_each+' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_cart" ><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></button>';

          var t = $( "#tables" ).DataTable();
          t.row.add([customer_name_each,
            customer_address_each,
            customer_email_each,
            customer_number_each,
            store_location_each,
            customer_order_note_each,
            customer_registered_each,
            action_each]).draw();

        })
    }

  });
});
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. "*is there way to load every seconds the datatable*", do you mean you want to re-load the datatable every second? Or just when there is a change?

Comment: Also DataTables offers built in Remote Data sourcing: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: @Twisty hi twisty, sorry for that. What i mean for this, i want realtime if i click submit the data from database will appear to the table without refresh

Comment: What script do you have to update your database then? You can post data to that PHP Script and then refresh the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Making an ajax request and then looping through the rows and adding the rows to the datatable, I think you should just use ajax sourced data to datatable. You can change the format of data through datasrc if you cannot change the ajax data format.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

and then you once user registers, you can create a Update request to source and then reload the datatable which will get latest data right after the user updates.

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/UpdateTableData',
                    data: parameter,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var table = $('#dtexample').DataTable();
                        table.draw('page');
                    }
                });
```